# wdWrapBehind in word (2003) vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am having problems getting my pictures to wrap behind the text in Word 2003 using VBA. I can use all the other wrapping options fine but when I try and use wdWrapBehind I get the following error.

"Compile Error: Variable not defined"

I have had a hunt around through google with no luck.

Code:

```
      Dim shape1 As shape
      Dim imagePath1 As String

      imagePath1 = "C:\image.jpg"

      Set shape1 = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(imagePath1)

      With shape1
        .ScaleHeight 1, msoTrue
        .ScaleWidth 1, msoCTrue
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind
        .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
        .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
        .Left = InchesToPoints(0.433)
        .Top = InchesToPoints(0.413)
      End With
```

Any help appreacited!

Cheers,
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to get it to work by adding these 4 lines instead of wdWrapBehind.

```
        .WrapFormat.AllowOverlap = True
        .WrapFormat.Side = wdWrapBoth
        .WrapFormat.Type = 3
        .ZOrder 5
```

Full code:

```
    Dim shape1 As shape         
    Dim imagePath1 As String            
    imagePath1 = "C:\image.jpg"            
    Set shape1 = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(imagePath1)   

    With shape1
        .ScaleHeight 1, msoTrue
        .ScaleWidth 1, msoCTrue
        .WrapFormat.AllowOverlap = True
        .WrapFormat.Side = wdWrapBoth
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .WrapFormat.Type = 3
        .ZOrder 5
        .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
        .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
        .Left = InchesToPoints(6.889)
        .Top = InchesToPoints(0.374)
    End With
```